# How to solve Not Found (HTTP 404) in textaDetectTopics from mscstexta4r in R?

Tags: r, azure-cognitive-services, text-analysis

I'm trying `mscstexta4r` in **R** and it is working when I use `textaSentiment` command but, when I try `textaDetectTopics` it returns:

```
[1] "mscstexta4r: Not Found (HTTP 404). - { \"statusCode\": 404, \"message\": \"Resource not found\" }"
```

My *.mscskeys.json* file configuration is:

```
{
"textanalyticsurl": "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/texta/analytics/v2.0/",
"textanalyticskey": "--my API key--"
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topic detection has been deprecated from the Text Analytics API for several months now.  That's why you are getting the 404.